# Replace dot by comma in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have got a model in my Asp.Net MVC application which receives data from the server.

```
public class Article
{
    public decimal? Stock { get; set; }
}
```

The problem though, my `NumericTextBox()` inside the view uses "de-DE" globalization. So instead of "55.50" we use commas like "55,50".
Because of this there are issues.
The TextBox expects the value to be in the comma seperator format but the data from the server is in the dot seperator format.

Is there any rule or something which I can apply in the `web.config` or some replace function in order to change the server side values to comma seperated ones?

Comment: You can make a function into your controller/helper where you fill your model. And call it when you use 'de-DE' globalization.

Comment: currently I fill my model with var result = articleContext.Articles.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: How would it do it?

Comment: result is an article or multiple articles, right ?

Comment: It is a single article of the article class which is shown above. There are more variables inside the class but for readability I am only showing the Stock variable.

Comment: First thing, if your object is an Article, declare it with : `Article() result = new Article();`
Second thing, you will have to change the type of your variable into Article object. I think that you can simply replace , with . because your variable is decimal. It should be string.
Then you can replace your char with string.replace function.

Comment: I can't change the type of my Stock variable. It has to fit with those of the SQL Server and they are decimal. I don't have access to the database.

Comment: You don't have to change your database. You should change only your model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149164/discussion-between-bob-swager-and-anokrize).

Comment: It is a terrible idea to replace the nullable decimal with a string. If you were going to go some route like that, then you would do it with another property. You certainly wouldn't change a property on a model used to back data from a database to a data type that makes no sense.

Comment: Why fight it? Make sure  your Region and Language is correct on ALL servers, let the framework handle this.

Comment: Numeric data stored in binary format - its representation depends on regional settings used in server machine. It is a bad idea to use string that replace decimal values, requiring extra casts when doing arithmetic operations & may incur performance penalty on some cases.